# Do all versions of Office 2019 have Design Ideas and 3D Objects in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2019

I am interested in buying Office 2019 Home and Student as I only need Word, PowerPoint, and Excel. Will I be getting Design Ideas and 3D Objects in PowerPoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will I be getting Design Ideas and 3D Objects in PowerPoint?

Design Ideas is only a feature of Office 365 which requires a subscription.  You will NOT get it if you purchase Office 2019 which while has features from Office 365 but only from 
October 2018

> This is a subscriber-only, Office 365 feature. If you don't see the Design Ideas button, or you don't see certain features described on this page, read Requirements below for more details.

You also get the feature if you have access to PowerPoint Online

[Create professional slide layouts with PowerPoint Designer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-professional-slide-layouts-with-powerpoint-designer-53c77d7b-dc40-45c2-b684-81415eac0617)

> Don't you think that it should be in Home and Student version too as it requires us to spend 150 dollars?

Does not matter what I or anyone thinks.

Comment: Or you could buy Office 365, and cancel your subscription after a year.

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi - Sure; After a year you can’t use it, which is the reason, the student deal is so nice.

Comment: @EngSoonCheah - This question has nothing to do with Office 2016.

Comment: @Ramhound how about Office 2019? I still can't see the Design Idea. Even go to Option> General Tab.

Comment: Design Ideas is a Office 365 only feature.  Please read my answer again.  **I specifically stated, Office 2019 does not get, featured ideas which is specifically a feature of Office 365.**